# Setting up FLTK in Xcode

Tags: xcode, fltk

I'm new to Xcode and now I'm trying to set up FLTK environment. FLTK provides me with a xcode project `FLTK.xcodeproj` and I was wondering how I could use it to create my own FLTK project in which I could add `fltk.framework` as a library, which is already added in `FLTK.xcodeproj`.

Thanks in advance.